# Collection_select is not saving the data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I encounter some problems in a simple action that I want to execute. 
To explain the context, I'm creating new Pin where we can tag the artist of the painting (:pin_maker) from User table. The only condition is that the User is an artist
Currently, all seems good, but when I run the create function, it's not saving my Artist selection(or :pin maker)

My code :

The scope for te Artist =

```
scope :artist, -> { where(artist: true) }
```

new pin(views) =

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.collection_select(:pin_maker, @users, :id, :pseudo, { }, {:multiple => true}) %>
```

controller pin =

```
    class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :find_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :downvote]

  def index 
    @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end 

  def show 
  end 



  def new
   @pin = Pin.new
   @users = User.all.artist
  end

  def create 
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
    if @pin.save 
      redirect_to @pin, notice: "successfully created!"
    else 
      render 'new'
    end
  end 

  def edit 

  end 

  def update 
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: "successfully updated !"
    else 
      render 'edit'
    end
  end 

  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end 

  def upvote 
    @pin.upvote_from current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end 

  def downvote
    @pin.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end 

  private



  def pin_params
    params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :description, :image, :pin_maker)
  end 

  def find_pin
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
  end 

end
```

So if you ave any idea of what I should change to fix that, I'm here !

Comment: Please provide your controller code

Comment: Done, but I think there is no special info inside

Comment: @MoatazZaitoun This can work if :pin_maker it's an integer ? If the user want to save many artist ?

Comment: I don't know, try replace `params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :description, :image, :pin_maker)` with `params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :description, :image, :pin_makers => [])`

Comment: The thing you cant isolate a block of code from it's context, Some times you need to review the whole three Model, View and Controller to debug

Comment: Tanks @MoatazZaitoun, well I finally found the problem, it's about the multiple selection. Because if I do the action deleting , { }, {:multiple => true}, it's working. So can I save diffrents id in a unique integer or should I create a new table for that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125042/discussion-between-moataz-zaitoun-and-tutoto).